# Eliminating Queries in Django

Tags: python, django, query-optimization, django-queryset, querying

I have a situation where I'd like to get the most popular comment for each thread in a list of threads. As it stands currently I'm doing a query within a for loop, which is predictably quite slow. Is there a way to eliminate the deluge of queries this creates?

Using Django's `prefetch_related` queryset method isn't acceptable, seeing as retrieves all of the comments related to a thread (which could potentially be quite a lot). This is especially problematic seeing as I only need one comment per thread (only the most popular one).

Here's a simplified version of my models (a bunch of unrelated information was removed for brevity).

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    def description(self):
        """ Returns most popular post based on votes. """
        return self.posts.annotate(_popularity=models.Count('votes')).order_by('-_popularity')[0]

class Post(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey('Thread', related_name='posts')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=settings.MAX_POST_LENGTH)

class Vote(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', related_name='votes')
```

The code that gets all of the descriptions is effectively this. `threads` is an already evaluated queryset of `Thread` objects.

```
def descriptions(threads):
     for thread in threads:
         yield thread.description()
```

So basically I have some threads, and I'm looking to get a list containing the most popular comment for each thread. I'm looking to do this with fewer than `N` queries, where `N` is the number of threads.

Comment: Do you happen to be using Postgres?

Comment: In production yes, though I'm using SQLite for dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are at least two solutions. One (since you're using Postgres) is to make use of [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#distinct). The other is to drop down to raw sql. The former is simpler so that's the one I'll write up a code example for.

```
most_popular_posts = Post.objects.all().annotate(
    popularity=Count('votes__id', distinct=True)
).select_related('thread').distinct('thread_id').order_by(
    '-thread_id', '-popularity'
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was avoiding this solution because it was DB specific. However, after doing quite a bit of searching/thinking, I'm pretty sure this is the best/only solution to my problem, without dropping down to raw SQL.

Comment: To be honest, I probably spent an hour writing this little answer and went through 5 different solutions before arriving at this one. It's an interesting edge case.

Comment: Same (though I spent about 3), I saw `distinct('some_field')` in the docs and was apprehensive due to it being DB specific. I was hoping I overlooked something, or that there was a clever approach to this. However, I think you nailed it. Again thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are very close to having the correct answer.

```
def handle_popular_posts(threads):
  most_popular_posts = Posts.objects                 \
        .filter(thread__id__in=threads)              \
        .annotate(_popularity=models.Count('votes')) \
        .order_by('-_popularity').select_related('thread')
  for post in most_popular_posts:
     #your_code_here...
```

I added the `.select_related('thread')` since it is my belief that you will want the information about the parent thread and without `select_related` Django will make a new query each time you try to access a threads information beyond the id.

This query should be quite efficient as I ran a similar case on one of my databases with hundreds of rows and it took **~10ms**. While a single get with an id takes about **~5ms** on this database.

Comment: Doesn't this return all of the posts for a thread? In the question it says that OP doesn't want to do that.